# What is the best way to design voltage monitor with tri-colour LED?

Tags: voltage, led, comparator, monitor

I've built a power supply with regulated +15v, +12v, +5v, -12v and -15v outputs and I'd like to build a voltage monitor to let me know if any of the rails are above or below their stated voltage.

I have some tri-colour RGB LEDs (common cathode), the plan is that when the rail is at the correct voltage, the LED is green, it goes red when it detects over-voltage and blue if there's under-voltage (say, ~20mV either way).

I've tried building a circuit with the LM3914 bargraph driver chip but the problem with this is it requires a common anode LED if I want to use an RGB.  Also the chip is a 10 LED output and it seems wasteful to only use 3 outputs.

I've done some research and it seems like I could get something to work with op-amp comparators and either zener diodes or regulators as a reference but I don't really know enough about this yet.

Could someone please give me some advice with regards to the best way to go about this?

Comment: When you type 'voltage comparator' in google you get 13 million hits, many with descriptions and schematics. What do you want us to add to that 13Million?

Comment: Try searching "window comparator"

Comment: By "best" do you mean to include "gold-plated" as in traceable to NIST voltage standards? You mention \$-20\:\text{mV}\$ as being enough to be under-voltage. Even the [ISL21009BFB850](https://www.intersil.com/en/products/data-converters/voltage-references/voltage-references/ISL21009BFB850.html) considers \$\pm\:2\:\text{mV}\$ initial accuracy to be "something good," though you can buy even better. Are you serious about the \$\pm 20\:\text{mV}\$ ***accuracy*** window?

Comment: Thanks, window comparator seems to come up with the right sort of info, I'm investigating now.

Comment: I'm not sure I need to go so far as to satisfy NIST voltage standards, but the more accurate the better, I suppose.  the PSU is for a modular synth so any voltage drop will affect tuning etc. s Ideally, less than +/-20mV, maybe as little as +/-5mV.   The idea is to have a monitor to let me know when something is not right.  I don't really want to go as far as having a voltmeter on each rail because I can't really dedicate that much front panel.

Comment: I don't have much to add. It sounds like a very tough problem. See what I wrote here: [accuracy and reproducibility](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/310436/how-to-improve-resolution-and-presicion-of-sensor-reading/310500#310500). If you are going to design that power supply, reproducible at accuracies anywhere near \$\pm 5\:\text{mV}\$, including low drift internal self-accuracy measurement of same in order to validate those output voltages, please write me and let me know about it. I may want to buy a few.

Comment: as bad as that!  OK, looks like I have to go back to the drawing board.  thanks

Comment: Is there a special purpose for this set of rails? Where did you get the requirement for +-20mV? Normal good supplies will have 50 mV just in ripples, and load regulation barely at 100mV. What kind of loads do you plan to handle?

Comment: Also, a bargraph chip has a set of configurable comparators, which is already a big asset as compared to three-level loose comparator ICs, so using 3 outputs is not a "waste" whatsoever.

Comment: Another important thing to check: does your load have power sequencing requirements, e.g. the +5V rail not being allowed to have a higher voltage than the +12V rail? What happens if the +12V rail fails or starts up slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks for the tip on using the bargraph meter chip, I've persevered and come up with this:

[image: LM3914 15v Monitor]

I found this article on Nuts and Volts which gives details on using the LM3914 and getting the best out of it:  http://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/led-graph-circuits.

The circuit works pretty well, the sensitivity can be adjusted by varying the 'window' set with the trimmers R2 & R3, and also by choosing different LED outputs.  The green 'normal' LED needs to be on LED_5, pin 14.

Answer (score 0):

I've made something similar for motorcycles using an ATTiny chip.
A simple board with a duo LED on it that indicates the board voltage.

I used the ATTiny10 to be precise, which is a fun little **6 pin** microcontroller.

The chip is ridiculously limited in capabilities, with on 1024 bytes of ROM and 32 bytes of RAM. You can barely compile C for it. But what it has to do is also very simplistic, so a perfect fit.