# What is the triangle symbol in circuit diagrams?

Tags: digital-logic, clock, flipflop, register, vlsi

What is the triagular symbols shown in the image, is it a buffer or some kind of delay?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a non-inverting buffer, but could just be indicating the direction the signal is being driven.  In this example it could possibly be to introduce a delay so the clocks are triggered right-to-left rather than all at once

Comment: Given the title "controlling clock skew" it indicates a buffer, which adds some skew.

Comment: Please accept an answer as solution once it solves your problem. I have noticed that you are asking questions here, but you never acknowledge any of the answers till now. That's not a fruitful way of using EESE.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's the standard representation of a [buffer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236666/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-buffer-gate). What you see are clock buffers which are present there to not degrade the rise and fall times of the clock. As typically clock nets have high fan-out, you need high drive strength to ensure that a nice square wave reaches all the registers.

And yes, it introduces a delay in that path. For instance, in your particular example, the clock edge reaches `U2` slightly later than at `U3`, approximately equal to the buffer delay \$\delta\$. This difference is called [clock skew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_skew).